# Про контент div:before

Tags: html, css

Как увеличить расстояние между div:before и содержащим? Я создал линию над заголовком, но никак не получается чуть увеличить расстояние между ними.

```css
.sectionTitle {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-size: 4.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.552rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

.sectionTitle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 5.5rem;
  height: 0.4rem;
  background: #7a7a7a;
  left: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionTitle"></div>
```

Comment: Зависит от того, как именно создали

Comment: .sectionTitle{
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    font-size: 4.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.552rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
}
.sectionTitle:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 5.5rem;
    height: 0.4rem;
    background: #7a7a7a;
    left: 0.3rem;
}

Comment: Что конкретно вам необходимо сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.sectionTitle {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-size: 4.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.552rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  padding-top: 50px; /* 2 - делаем отступ сверху, увеличивая расстояние */
}

.sectionTitle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 5.5rem;
  height: 0.4rem;
  background: #7a7a7a;
  left: 0.3rem;
  top: 0; /* 1 - позиционируем элемент по верхнему краю родителя */
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionTitle">123</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все вышло благодаря вашей помощи!